# Update a dropdown list value and process it via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

HTML:

```
<select id="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>
<input value="load()" id="test" type="submit" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Script:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
cache: false  
}); 
var loadUrl = "http://localhost/test/process.php";  
    $("#test").click(function(){  
          $("#result").load(loadUrl, "content=sd345f"+singleValues);  
    });
    function displayVals() {
      var singleValues = $("#single").val();
    }
    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
```

That is my current code, I'm new to jquery and what i wanna ask is how do i make the var singleValues update when i choose a list from a dropdown and append it as a get value when i click on submit?

ANd here's process.php BTW:

```
<?php file_put_contents('1.txt',$_GET['content']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to load the result when you click on the button.

Try the following code:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    // get the selected value
    var value = $("#single option:selected").val();

    // GET to server
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost/test/process.php",
        data : {
            "content" : value
        }, 
        success : function(response){
            $("#result").html(response);
        }
    });
    // Don't use default submit function
    return false;
});
```

More information about $.ajax  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Only when i click on the submit button.

Comment: what if the dropdown and submit button was in a loop? http://pastebin.com/vTxGeEk4